# Export results from Orange3

Tags: orange

I'd like to build a service visualizing my data.

Orange3 provides good "Scatter Plot", "Freeviz" (and so on) widgets.

Is there a way to export my results to jupiter notebook or jpeg file/files, or maybe other options would be ok.

Note: if it is requires coding in python then it is ok, but i need a clue.

Edit: as far as i've investigated for now, i'll be ok with "Report" data from Orange. but i need a way (not exactly a full solution) how to implement to build it from code.

Answer (score 2):

If the actions you want to perform are included in the Orange3 [Data Mining Library](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/#tutorial), then you can perform your calculations via python code and extract the results in .txt or a .csv file.